# Parallax effect of UITextView to make UIImageView on top shrink and disappear in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextview, parallax

What I have so far is a `UITextView` covering the entire Screen. The `UIImageView` is set to the top of the same screen.

UITextView on `viewDidAppear` has its content offset by the `UIImageView` height so they dont overlap.

When the `UITextView` scrolls, I am trying updating its content offset so that the text moves up. Coincidentally, I want the `UIImageVIew` to move up at least.

The commented block was my first attempt, it moved the `UIImageView` up, but some constraints or something are blocking it to work 100%

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    print("scrollViewDidScroll Y offset:" + offsetY.description)
    print("Constraints: ")

    for constraint in detailImage!.constraints {
        print(constraint.description)
    }

    //imageFrame.origin.x = originImgFrameX
    //imageFrame.origin.y = originImgFrameY - offsetY
    //print("Origin is: \(imageFrame.origin.x, imageFrame.origin.y)")
    //detailImage!.frame = imageFrame;
    //print("IMG AFTER SCROLL: " + detailImage!.description)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing the moment with constraint instead of manipulating the frames... Especially if you set up the view with constraints in the interface builder.

You can ctrl drag constraints in to your code as outlets and then you can instead of changing the views `frame.y` change the `constraintOutlet.constant`

Comment: So I can specifically reference a SPECIFIC constraint? That would be useful, as you can see I tried enumerating them, but their description  and debugDescription properties are just awful....And I didn't even find the one that alings it to the superview at the top. This would be interesting indeed. But I am surprised no one did this? This iOS platform is really weird.....Fragmented so much, for so few physical devices that exist...

Comment: outlets for constraints are very useful indeed but it seems that it's not very well known off. I'm also surprised about how often developers doesn't know it's possible.